# PHP class properties inside properties

Tags: php, arrays, class, properties

Hey I have been reading some PHP class documentation and how to create classes. But I haven't seen any examples of properties inside the properties. I will give an example what I want to do:

```
class Properties {
public property1;
public nestedProperty1;
public nestedProperty2;
}
```

and I want to assign properties like this:

```
$Property = new Properties();
$Property->property1 = "foo";
$property1->nestedProperty1 = "bar";
```

So I could access data like:

```
$property1->nestedProperty1;
```

Is this possible? I need this because I'm working with a dynamic multidimentional array.

Comment: First one, you must have `$` at beginning of your variable - `public $property1;`

Second, if you want something like `$Property->property1->nestedProperty1`, you can assign `$Property->property1 = new Properties();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) classes != arrays.

2) You want nested CLASSES.

For example (pseudo code):

```
// Create a class
MyThingClass {
  string ThingProperty1
  int ThingProperty2
}

// Create a MyThingClass instance
MyThing = new MyThingClass(...)

// Use instance in another class
MyOtherThingClass {
  MyThingClass MyThing
  string SomeOtherProperty
}
```

You cannot nest properties directly like you are trying to do. You could also use structures as properties.